# Unity 3D Watson speech to text Error: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType' UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ibm-watson

I'm trying to use watson SpeechToText on Unity 3D but i get this Error.

```
[06/27/2020 02:30:22][SpeechToText.OnListenMessage()][ERROR] Error: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
IBM.Cloud.SDK.Debug.DebugReactor:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at Assets/unity-sdk-core-1.2.0/Debug/DebugReactor.cs:60)
IBM.Cloud.SDK.LogSystem:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at Assets/unity-sdk-core-1.2.0/Logging/Logger.cs:207)
IBM.Cloud.SDK.Log:Error(String, String, Object[]) (at Assets/unity-sdk-core-1.2.0/Logging/Logger.cs:280)
IBM.Watson.SpeechToText.V1.SpeechToTextService:OnListenMessage(Message) (at Assets/unity-sdk-4.5.0/Scripts/Services/SpeechToText/V1/SpeechToTextServiceExtension.cs:651)
IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.<ProcessReceiveQueue>d__49:MoveNext() (at Assets/unity-sdk-core-1.2.0/Connection/WSConnector.cs:430)
IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities.Routine:MoveNext() (at Assets/unity-sdk-core-1.2.0/Utilities/Runnable.cs:131)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I am also looking for the answer. It was working fine few months ago but now its not.

Answer (score 0):

Something in an old version broke after new changes to the backend.
Update to the latest sdks.

At the time of writing this comment, these are:
unity-sdk-4.7.1
unity-sdk-core-1.2.1

You can find the latest here:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/releases/latest